# how can i add rigify sample or how to using rigify dev tools?

Tags: rigify

I trying to rig a series of character,these rigs have the same feature.

I found rigify had 'sample' to create meta-rig,then using mata-rig to generate rig ,controller and IK/FK bones.

Now 'sample' don't have option  what i need（my character‘s arm have 3 bones),i can create 3 bones arm has controller and IK/FK bones myself,but i want to add my 3 bones arm to 'sample' so when i rig different 3 bones arm character , i can save a lot of time to create controller and IK/FK.

[image]

[image]

i found rigify panel have rigify dev tools

[image]

where can i get tutorial to learn it?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

check here it just saved as a bpy, the way to use is clicking run:)

Comment: Hi could you explain where "here" is? Your screenshot is severy cropped and it may not be immediately obvious where this is located. Also this site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, that would be great.